# Without looping through the string, how can I grab all integers from said string? String class methods?

Tags: c++, regex, string

### Rule I must abide by

Do not use loops or character arrays to process strings for any of the questions below. Use member functions of the string class. You can use a loop to read the file and to count the number of processors.

### Some Tips

Here are some functions that you might find useful:

- File class: getline
- String class: find, rfind, substr, length, c_str, constant npos
- Misc. functions: atoi, atof
    (may require the C standard library for C++, i.e., )
  isstringstream
      (Both of the above are ways to convert a string to a number.)

Here is an example string I would need to extract:

```
"46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual"
```

I can go through the same string twice.  I'd want to grab 46 and store it and then do the same for 48.

I'm not sure the best way to go about this. Is it possible to do something like this:

```
string.find_first_of(integer);
string.find_last_not_of(integer);
```

Or possibly regex?  I think I can use that as long as I don't need to use a 3rd party library or anything like that.

Comment: What's your question, exactly? You've got an idea there, let's see it happen.

Comment: Regex is part of the Standard Library which come with the latest C++ versions.

Comment: *If* you can use regular expressions, you can get a set of matches for all numbers without an explicit loop over the string. You still need a loop to *print* (as strings) the numbers though.

Comment: All loops can be replaced by `goto`, recursion, or (teachers usually forget about this one) `setjmp`/`longjmp`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I saw you deleted your answer, was that because it used a loop?  Regex is kind of confusing to me so I was going to try the way you suggested.  If it is in the STL like Quentin said then I can use it.

Comment: @Rfjt The STL is not the standard library (but some parts of the STL were added to the standard library a couple of years ago).

Comment: [This reference is good](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) but might be tough for beginners. There are plenty of tutorials if you just search a little though. And yes my (deleted) answer was looping over the string.

Answer (score 0):

The following ended up working for me.

```
#include <sstream>

string myString = "hello 47";

int val;

istringstream iss (myString);

iss >> val;

cout << val << endl;

// The output of val will be 47.
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you indicated in the comments that STL is allowed, you can use a generic programming approach relying on STL algorithms. For example,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>


int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    string haystack = "46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual";
    string result;

    remove_copy_if(begin(haystack), end(haystack),
                   back_inserter(result),
                   [](char c) { return !isspace(c) && !isdigit(c); } );
    cout << result;
}
```

You basically treat the characters in the string as a stream of inputs, from that just filter out all non-digit characters and keeping whatever delimiter char you want to use. My example keeps whitespace as delimiter.

The above gives the output

> 46   48